# Source code sharing using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

I tried github but could not find how to use it.

Actually what I want is that in eclispe I should be able to open project and all class files like in project explorer and it saves on server and then on other computer I have same project explorer of left and same files.

Is it possible?

Comment: your question is very vague and hard to understand, please edit your question and make it clearer. Do you want to put or **upload your** project on github? Or do you want to **download** and project from github?

Comment: i want to upload existing classes to github and then use from there

Comment: I think you should read the github documentation and understand it before you complain that it doesn't do what you want! The documentation is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some tutorials, searching "github eclipse turorial".

Example: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html

Example: http://loianegroner.com/2009/11/tutorial-using-the-egit-eclipse-plugin-with-github/

I think it will do what you want.

Comment: The first link is broken, could you please update it..?

Answer (score 0):

Try SubEclipse
http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a versioning system. Try SVN or CVS

http://www.visualsvn.com/

http://subversion.tigris.org/

http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/